# bash brace expansion for PATH-like variables

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I need to set a variable like this:

```
./configure ... PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/imagemagick/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/gnutls/lib/pkgconfig
```

An obvious way to make is readable is to use [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/{libxml2,imagemagick,gnutls}/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH// /:}
```

However, this does not work (brace expansion does not happen in the variable setting and, also, when the expansion *is* done, the separator is a *space* and there appears to be no way to change that.

So, is there a way to avoid the ugliness of the explicit prefix and suffix for each package?

Comment: "The separator is a space"? Brace expansion doesn't create "spaces" or any other characters at all; it creates *words*, with prefix and suffix contents duplicated. Those words are completely separate C strings; you don't have a single string that has literal spaces in it, you have *separate, independent strings*, one for each result. This is akin to how `"${array[@]}"` doesn't insert spaces between your array elements -- rather, it expands them to one word per.

Comment: That's why the array approach in chepner's answer works -- an array can store multiple independent strings -- and why the original code didn't -- because you were expanding into a context (assignment to a scalar/string-type variable) where multiple strings weren't valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is for a script, and not interactive use, I'd just use an array.

```
pkg_config_path=(
 /usr/local/opt/{libxml2,imagemagick,gnutls}/lib/pkgconfig
)
./configure ... PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(IFS=:; printf %s "${pkg_config_path[*]}")
```

At this point, you might want to consider whether to bother with brace expansion and just list the directories explicitly:

```
pkg_config_path=(
  /usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig
  /usr/local/opt/imagemagick/lib/pkgconfig
  /usr/local/opt/gnutls/lib/pkgconfig
)
```